# "grunt" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. en windows 11

Tags: npm, grunt

Saludos estoy comenzando a usar npm y estoy tratando de seguir un proceso de automatizando tareas en el código con grunt, el detalle es que aunque tengo grunt instalado version 8.11.0

y supuestamente (digo supuestamente porque lo instalo npm install grunt --save-dev y luego npm install grunt-cli --save-dev ) pero al colocar grunt en la consola de comandos
me indica:"grunt" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

tengo Windows 11 no se si sea esta la razón

Comment: normalmente cuando instalas algo en windows (Cualquier version) requiere que reinicies el Ordenador; para que las configuraciones/variables globales tomen efecto...

Comment: verificaste mi respuesta???

Comment: saludos si, y aun así sigue igual

Comment: ok ya eso debe ser por algun problema o inestabilidad de tu sistema operativo... puedes ofrecer una captura de editor de tus variables de entorno?

Comment: esta tarde lo hago, de momento no estoy en ese equipo pero esta tarde me comprometo a hacer las verificaciones he indicaciones que de manera tan gentil me han dado como luces en mi camino

Answer (score 0):

Esto courre cuando al realizar la instalacion; las variables globales no se guardan en el sistema operativo, normalmente esto debe resolver el problema:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\[tu Usuario]\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

recuerda sustituir ***[tu Usuario]*** con el nombre de la carpeta del usuario.

Comment: lo pruebo esta tarde perdonen lo tardío en contestar y gracias por plantear una posibilidad de ser acertada lo indico